# proof-based Pos type class

Tags: lean4, natural-numbers

I'm working my way through the [chapter on type classes](https://leanprover.github.io/functional_programming_in_lean/type-classes/pos.html) in *Functional Programming in Lean*. The text demonstrates type-classes by representing positive numbers this way:

```
inductive Pos : Type where
 | one : Pos
 | succ : Pos → Pos
```

The first exercise then asks the reader to represent them this way:

```
structure Pos where
  succ ::
  pred : Nat
```

I completed the exercise, and then wondered how it would be to simply package together a natural number and a proof that it's positive. This is what I have so far:

```
structure Pos where
  n: Nat
  nPos: n > 0

structure Pos where
  n: Nat
  nPos: n > 0

def Pos.add : Pos → Pos → Pos
  | Pos.mk n _, Pos.mk k _ => Pos.mk (n + k) sorry

instance : Add Pos where
  add := Pos.add

def seven : Pos :=
  Pos.mk 7 sorry

def fourteen : Pos := seven + seven

def Pos.toNat : Pos → Nat
  | Pos.mk n _ => n

instance : ToString Pos where
  toString x := toString (x.toNat)

#eval s!"There are {seven}"

def Pos.mul : Pos → Pos → Pos
  | Pos.mk n _, Pos.mk k _=> Pos.mk (n*k) sorry

instance : Mul Pos where
  mul := Pos.mul

#eval [seven * (Pos.mk 1 sorry),
       seven * seven,
       (Pos.mk 2 sorry) * seven]

instance : OfNat Pos (n + 1) where
  ofNat := Pos.mk (n+1) sorry

def eight : Pos := 8
```

Obviously this is no good because I don't know what to put instead of `sorry` in several places. Lean wouldn't accept `Pos.mk 7 (7 > 0)`, but I don't quite understand the error message:

```
application type mismatch
  { n := 7, nPos := 7 > 0 }
argument
  7 > 0
has type
  Prop : Type
but is expected to have type
  7 > 0 : Prop
```

I would also need a proof that adding two positives or multiplying two positives give another positive, which is intuitively obvious but I don't know if Lean has built-in knowledge for it.

I think this approach is probably too cumbersome, but I would like to complete it just to see how it would play out. How should I fill in the `sorry`'s in my code?

Comment: Writing `Pos.mk 7 (7 > 0)` is the same sort of mistake as writing `7 + Nat`. You wrote a *type* `7 > 0` where its *element* was required.

Answer (score 2):

`7 > 0` is a statement that can be either true or false. However what you need to provide is a *proof* of `7 > 0`. Repeating the theorem statement doesn't count as a proof.

Think about how you will fill the following `sorry`:

```
theorem pos_seven : 7 > 0 := by sorry
```

Comment: I agree, except I would delete the "can be either true or false" part, for educational reasons.

Comment: Well, the magic formula for this particular part happens to be `(by decide)`. I still don't know what to put in add, mul, or ofNat.